# DBAppender - how to change default table names?

Tags: java, logback

Is it possible to change the default table names for `DBAppender` in Logback and how can I do it ?

P.S. Browsing the sources I found that `DBAppender` uses the `DBNameResolver` interface for getting table names, I can implement this interface in a custom-made `dbNameResolver` and then use custom-made table names, but the major problem for me is how to set that custom-made `dbNameResolver` into my `DBAppender`... is that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the API docs](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/db/DBAppender.html), it appears that `DBAppender` has a `setDbNameResolver()` property which could be invoked programatically, or, if I've understood how the configuration file works properly, just using something like:

```
<appender name="DB" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
   <.../>
   <dbNameResolver class="fqdn.to.my.DBNameResolver"/>
</appender>
```